# BinyOn or binyAn adai-ad in one of the sheva brochos?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, wedding, sheva-brachos

At a chupah today, in the brocho of “*asher yotzar es ho’odom betzalmo*” a learned Rabbi said the word “*binyOn*” before “*adai-ad*” rather than the more usual “*binyAn*”. “*binyOn*” is the text in the Baer siddur. I was told that the word “*binyan*” cannot be construct in Biblical Hebrew with “*adai-ad*”. Should I change (if I ever get the *brocho*)?

Comment: It is always *binyan*. If you're asking, is it a *patach* or a *kamatz*, that is a different question - but pronouncing a *kamatz* as "*O*" is wrong, the correct pronounciation is still *"A"* (though probably a bit closer to *"uh"*).

Comment: @AviD What about the "_O_" in mod, cob, sod, fodder, top or slot? Vowel notation in English is so irregular (not to mention differences in US, UK, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa etc.) that any transliteration scheme is basically arbitrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're right that, in Biblical Hebrew, *binyan* cannot be construct with *ade ad*:

- For one thing, *ade ad* is not used as the complement of a construct noun in *Tanach*.

  For another, *ade ad* seems to be an adverb:

  - It seems to be used as an adverb wherever it appears (Is. 65:18; Ps. 83:18, 92:8, 132:12,14).

    Moreover, *ade* is the same as (the preposition) *ad* (much as *ale asor vaale navel* is the same as *al asor v'al navel*), which would make the use of *ade ad* as an adverb seem plausible.

  Since a noun can't be used as an adverb (or at least I can't think of a noun used as an adverb: normally, one would need to add a prepositional prefix (clitic), as in *l'ol'me ad*), that would imply *ade ad* is not a noun. Then it can't be the complement of a construct noun.

But *b'rachos* are generally in rabbinic, not Biblical, Hebrew (when they're not paraphrasing *Tanach*), and rabbinic Hebrew may have different rules about *ade ad*: I don't know.

You ask what you should do if you're saying this *b'racha*. For practical guidance, one should always follow his rabbi's ruling, irrespective of what one reads on this site.